# Why xdebug.so is not in php 8 folder when installing from homebrew?

Tags: php, homebrew, xdebug

So I installed php 8 with homebrew and I got the PHP 8 installation folder. However, I am trying to connect xdebug with phpstorm. So when I got to the step of linking the 'zend_extension=' path, the PHP 8.0.1 folder didn't contain xdebug.so(I've looked and searched everywhere it doesn’t exist), I have other versions of PHP like 7.3 and 7.4, and they have xdebug within them maybe its cause I didn't use homebrew to install the 7.3 and 7.4 versions or maybe something else I don't know. I've tried deleting version PHP 8 and installing it again but that won't give me the extensions folder which contains xdebug.so, so I can add that path to the 'zend_extension='

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Xdebug extension is not automatically installed by homebrew by default, but you can easily install it using `pecl`:

```sh
$ cd /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.0.10/bin
$ ./pecl install xdebug
```

Comment: when i do pecl install xdebug i get command not found in mac terminal

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer, please try again. Please also make sure to use the correct PHP version of your installed PHP in the path.